# First cURL request validating GCM api key

Tags: android, curl, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently trying to build my first android app with a GCM API key which will be used by a piece of marketing software to send push notifications.

Wanted to get some help validating my google cloud message (GCM) API key with a curl request. I've tried using a online curl builder but the results dont match the success or error message im expecting.

The below request has been copied from the push sdk documentation. If it comes back with a 401 error i need to update my GCM project to a FCM project.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyBIuNzItgztXS31MYdl0xnszQcAUO7lbOg"
--header Content-Type:"application/json"
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

I would obviously love to know how to do this myself also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Chris. Just to clarify, you were wondering how to send a simple request to verify the Server Key validity?

Comment: Hi AL. Yes thats correct. If you receive the following response, the API Key is valid.

{"multicast_id":5464097959083008962,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":
[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

However, if you receive this response, the API key is invalid and you must go to step 4:

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Have you considered using [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26577/sending-downstream-messages-using-postman#t=201705230456569285061) to try it?

Comment: Sorry for replying again AL. but it seems I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting a bad request - See: http://imgur.com/a/J3Mfl

Comment: Hey @chris. No problem. The JSON in your request should be included in the *Body* tab, not in the URL itself. Then remove the `-d` part as well. Also, as best practice, always avoid disclosing your Server Key (the value used for Authorization) to the public. :)

Comment: @AL. thanks I'll give that a go tomorrow as im just about to shutdown

Comment: No worries. I'll add in an answer with the steps and screenshots so you could check it later too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you could try sending a simple downstream message using Postman.

1. Set request type to `POST` and provide the URL.

   [image]
2. Set the headers:

   - `Authorization` = `=<Server Key>` (here, when you're just starting, it is suggested to proceed with using FCM instead of GCM, since a new valid Server Key can only be generated by creating a Firebase Project).
   - `Content-Type` = `application/json`

   [image]
3. Set the (JSON payload) body (as *raw*):

   ```
   {
       "registration_ids" : ["ABC"]
   }
   ```

   [image]
4. Click on  <kbd>Send</kbd> .

You should receive an `InvalidRegistration`, a `401`, or an `Invalid Legacy Server Key...` error:

- `InvalidRegistration` error means the token(s) are invalid, but the Server Key is valid.
- `401` means invalid credentials, for this particular request, it's the Server Key.
- `Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.` means you attempted to use an old format Server Key (like the one in your post). New Server Key's have more characters. Usual response is like this:

  ```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
      <H1>Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.</H1>
      <H2>Error 401</H2>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
  ```