# How can recover the GCM API key? or know which account have the GCM API key?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with the GCM API.

I have an application developed by other person in my company a few months ago and he is no longer working in the company, the problem is that in this moment the GCM API is response with the error “Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request”, I found that this error occurred because the key is deleted but I don’t know with which account was created this key and I can’t change the key by a new key because I need send a notification to all devices and the new key require that the devices to be registered again.
How can recover the key? or know which account have the key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't recover the Server Key. The Invalid Legacy Server Key doesn't signify that the key was deleted, it's just that you're using an old API key (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132072/4625829)) and should use the **Server key with a new format** -- this is automatically generated by importing the corresponding project to Firebase, then going to the Project Settings > Cloud Messaging tab.

The tokens are not tied to the Server Key, it is only used for authorization when sending the messages. The tokens are instead, tied to the corresponding Sender ID.

If you have no way of identifying which project owns it, you should reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) directly, providing as much details as you can.